# Value get changed even though I'm not using reference

Tags: c++, reference

In code:

```
struct Rep
    {
        const char* my_data_;
        Rep* my_left_;
        Rep* my_right_;
        Rep(const char*);
    };

typedef Rep& list;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list& a_list)
    {
        int count = 0;
        list tmp = a_list;//----->HERE I'M CREATING A LOCAL COPY
        for (;tmp.my_right_;tmp = *tmp.my_right_)
        {
            out << "Object no: " << ++count << " has name: " << tmp.my_data_;
            //tmp = *tmp.my_right_;
        }
        return out;//------>HERE a_list is changed
    }
```

I've thought that if I'll create local copy to a_list object I'll be operating on completely separate object. Why isn't so?

Thanks.

Comment: `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const list& a_list)` - compiler error. What is `list`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your `list`?  It's apparently not `std::list`.

Comment: @Alexey Malistov && Kristo I've updated my post. I'm sorry guys for this overlook.

Comment: And how could `a_list` be changed by returning an `ostream &` from a function?  Your code doesn't modify `a_list` or `tmp`.

Comment: This can't be right. You can't have a reference to a reference. Did you mean to have a reference in the typedef?

Comment: `const list& a_list` - compiler error, reference to reference is illegal.
`list tmp = a_list;` - compiler error. const ref -> non-const ref.

Comment: @GMan && Alexey it does compiles in VS2010 RC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `list` is meant to be the same as `Rep`.

You are only copying the the pointer to the first node in the list. You are not copying the data, nor the rest of the nodes of the list. You are doing a *shallow copy* of the first node of the list. If you would also copy the objects themselves it would be *deep copy*.

Comment: So does it mean that I would have to provide cpy ctor for Rep in order to make this code work correctly?

Comment: Yes, you will have to do that, one that traverses the list and makes a copy of each node and each node's data.

Comment: He is not making a copy of the pointer.  He is making deep copies of the Rep structs (into a local Rep struct), but a shallow copy of the list of which the Reps are elements.  But he is not changing the copy (except to copy next elements into it) or the objects to which the pointers in the Rep struct point, so I don't see where the changes he is referring to could happen.  Also, his for loop will miss the last element in his list, so he will have to restructure it.

Answer (score 4):

You've `typedef`'d `list` to be a `Rep &`.  That means `tmp` isn't a copy.  It's just another reference.  Anything you do to `tmp` will be done to `a_list`.

Answer (score 3):

`const list& a_list` - compiler error, reference to reference is illegal.

`tmp = *tmp.my_right_` is very bad. Use pointers instead of reference.
The thing is that `tmp` is reference to `a_list`. `a_list` is changed when you write
`tmp = *tmp.my_right_`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're rolling your own list as an educational exercise.  When you do this for real, know that the standard library provides all this functionality for you.

```
std::list<std::string> myData;

// One way to print everything in the list.
int count = 0;
for (std::list<std::string>::iterator i = myData.begin(); i != myData.end(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Object no: " << ++count << " has name: " << *i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm doing this as an exercise.